# Chef: create a user only for certain roles?

Tags: chef-infra, databags

I'd like to setup a user (called 'deployer'), but only for certain roles.

I'm using the [Opscode users cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users). I'm calling it from a 'base' (included by all other cookbooks) [wrapper cookbook](http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Chef_Cookbooks_Developer_Guide/04-Developer/06-Development_Resources/Chef_Cookbook_Design_Patterns/Wrapper_Cookbook_Pattern). So, users in my `data_bags/users` directory are getting created on all of my Chef nodes.

With that in mind, my 'deployer' user doesn't seem to belong in `data_bags/users/deployer.json`. (That would create it for all nodes.)

I'm thinking and exploring to find one or more clean ways to do this. My use case is probably not unusual, so I would hope to find an "easy" path with Chef to do what I need. My thoughts and ideas currently include:

1. I have not yet found the explicit code that reads from my 'users' data bag. After finding such code, perhaps I could adjust it to filter based on an attribute so that certain users are excluded unless a particular role is 'running'?
2. I may create a separate data bag, perhaps "foo-users", where 'foo' is the role. Then I could use the [Opscode users cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users) to use that particular data bag exactly when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [deployer](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/deployer) cookbook. This cookbook is complimentary to the [users](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/users) cookbook, as it can leverage the same "users" databag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently leaning towards using this code for the roles where it is needed:

```rb
user "deployer" do
  comment "deployer account"
  supports manage_home: true
  shell "/bin/false"
end
```

Since I don't need the user to have a login shell, so keeping credentials hidden away in a data bag is not particularly important.

This would not be a clean solution if I had lots of user accounts that belonged on various combinations of machines. But for my case, it is simple and should work fine.